# the connectionstring property has not been initialized; Data type mismatch in criteria expression; database not updating

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# and the "the connectionstring property has not been initialized" is my problem. I've searched and tried everything I saw on the internet, but it doesn't help me at all. I don't know what to do anymore, Please help :(

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace salon
{
    public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        public Form4()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "/myDB.accdb";
        }

        private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'myDBDataSet.tblCustomerInfo' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tblCustomerInfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.myDBDataSet.tblCustomerInfo);

        }


        private void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();



                conn.Open();

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = @"insert into tblCustomerInfo(CustomerName, PhoneNo, Email) values ('" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtNo.Text + "','" + txtEmail.Text + "'";

                cmd.Connection = conn;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                conn.Close();


                string date = System.DateTime.Today.ToString("ddmmyy");
                MessageBox.Show("Your Information: " + Environment.NewLine + "Name: " + txtName.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Phone no.: " + txtNo.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Email: " + txtEmail.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Your chosen date is: " + timePicker.Value);



            MessageBox.Show("Your date is successfully reserved");
            Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
            frm1.Show();
            this.Hide();

        }


    }
}
```

Please help me with this one, I am new to c# and I don't know how to fix this. I tried searching and all but no luck. @un-lucky suggested parameterized queries but i don't know how to. I tried searching for it and no luck.

[data type mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls1Bg.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace salon
{
    public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        public Form4()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 

        }

        private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'myDBDataSet.tblCustomerInfo' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tblCustomerInfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.myDBDataSet.tblCustomerInfo);

        }


        private void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "/myDB.accdb";
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = conString;
                conn.Open();

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = @"insert into tblCustomerInfo(CustomerName, PhoneNo, Email) values ('" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtNo.Text + "','" + txtEmail.Text + "')";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", txtName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNo", txtNo.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                conn.Close();


                MessageBox.Show("Your Information: " + Environment.NewLine + "Name: " + txtName.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Phone no.: " + txtNo.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Email: " + txtEmail.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Your chosen date is: " + timePicker.Value);



            MessageBox.Show("Your date is successfully reserved");
            Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
            frm1.Show();
            this.Hide();

        }


    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I fixed the error about the data type mismatch but now when i start to debug it the database is not updating what's wrong? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize the ConnectionString property of the `OleDbCommand`, for that you can use the constructor or else you can initialize them later by setting the corresponding value to the property. Let `conString` be a global string variable which is used to store the connection string and are initialized like the following:

```
string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "/myDB.accdb"
```

Now you can define the connection like this

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conString );
```

or like this:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString =  conString;
```

Few other things that you have to notice is that:

- You have syntax errors in your insert query, that means you missed the closing bracket at the end of the query.
- Actually, using plain text queries will not be a good option, I strongly recommend you to use parameterization instead.

Comment: thanks but now I'm onto another error "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

Comment: and now "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." and it is pointing at the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: sorry for the extended question though

Comment: anyways how do I parameterize the queries, as I said i'm new here so i don't know about it